# NDOF device not working when I'm in "OOO orthographic" view

Tags: 3d-view, camera, navigation, 3d-mouse

I'm using "3Dconnexion Space Mouse Compact" as my NDOF device.

The 3D mouse works great, except **I can't orbit using the device when I'm in Front/Right/Top orthographic view** (which are accessed by pressing Numpad 1/3/7)

Only when I'm in arbitrary position (User Orthographic), the orbiting with 3D mouse is possible (fortunately, panning and zooming are fine in front/right/top orthographic view).

This is pretty annoying because I use Numpad 1/3/7 frequently to see my model in viewport.

Is there anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I keep waiting your help, guys...

However, I think I've found a bypass to get what I want.

In Blender preference, both [Numpad 1] and [Shift Numpad 1] are assigned to "3D View - View Axis".

I noticed both have exactly the same functionality, except the [Numpad 1] ends with "Front Orthographic" and [Shift Numpad 1] with "User Orthographic" (TOP and RIGHT view have also same logic).

So I converted the key-binding each other, and it worked as I want!

I'm satisfied a bit for now, but still want to know the reason why the NDOF device-orbiting not works in Not-User Orthographic view.

Comment: Same issue here, did you find a real solution?